# How can I turn an ordered tree into a collection of named nodes in Clojure?

Tags: recursion, clojure, tree

I think it's best to use an example. Let's say I have an ordered tree:

```
(def abcd [:a [:b :c] :d])
```

I want to build from it a collection of key-value maps, each map representing a nodes of this tree, with a random name and all relevant information, that is, its parent (nil for the root node) its index (0, 1, 2 ..) and, if it's a leaf node, its content (like ":a"). For instance, in this case it could be:

```clj
[{:name G__36654, :parent nil, :index 0}
 {:name G__36655, :content :a, :parent G__36654, :index 0}
 {:name G__36656, :parent G__36654, :index 1}
 {:name G__36657, :content :b, :parent G__36656, :index 0}
 {:name G__36658, :content :c, :parent G__36656, :index 1}
 {:name G__36659, :content :d, :parent G__36654, :index 2}]
```

I defined a function that seems to do what I want, but it uses recursion by calling itself and I'm having trouble figuring out how to use loop-recur instead, and I believe there must be something better out there. Here's my attempt:

```
(defn mttrav "my tree traversal"
  ([ptree parent index]
   (let [name (gensym)]
     (cond
       (not (coll? ptree)) [ {:name name :content ptree :parent parent :index index}]

       :else (reduce into
                     [{:name name  :parent parent :index index}]
                     (map-indexed #(mttrav %2 name  %1) ptree)))))
  ([ptree]
   (mttrav ptree nil  0)))
```

BTW, I don't know if a vector is the right collection to use, maybe a set would make more sense, but I'm using a vector for easier debugging, since it's more readable when the order in which nodes are generated is preserved, and if nodes are accidentally repeated I want to see it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: just to clarify, it would also be acceptable for each node to have a list of :child nodes instead of a :parent node, and some other variations, as long as it's a flat collection of maps, each map representing a node, with a unique :name, and the position, content and parent-child relations of the nodes are captured in this structure. The intended input are hiccup parse trees coming typically from Instaparse, and the maps are meant to become records to insert in a Clara session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breadth first traversal is  what you need.  So if you want to build the list of parents while you traverse the tree, you need to first uniquely identify all your leaf nodes. I'm not sure it can be done without doing that, except if you know for sure that your leafs nodes are unique. It's also getting really late/early here, so my brain is not working optimally. I'm sure my solution can get distilled down a lot.

So if you have a tree like [:a [:b :c] :d [:b :c]], [:b :c] is a parent of :b and :c, but then last two leaf nodes are also :b and :c, so which parent do you choose ?

So let's have a tree whose leaves have unique id.

```clj
(defn attach-ids [tree]
  (clojure.walk/postwalk (fn [node]
                           (if (coll? node) node
                               {:node node :id (gensym)}))
                         tree))


(def tree (attach-ids [:a [:b :c] :d]))

;; produces this
;; [{:node :a, :id G__21500}
;; [{:node :b, :id G__21501} {:node :c, :id G__21502}]
;;  {:node :d, :id G__21503}]
```

Now for the rest of the solution

```clj
(defn add-parent [parent-map id branch]
  (assoc parent-map id {:children-ids (set (map :id branch))
                        :child-nodes (map :node branch)}))


(defn find-parent-id [node parent-map]
  (->> parent-map
    (filter (fn [[parent-id {children-ids :children-ids}]]
              (contains? children-ids (:id node))))
    ffirst))


(defn find-index [node parent-map tree]
  (if-let [parent-id (find-parent-id node parent-map)]
    (let [children (:child-nodes (get parent-map parent-id))]
      (.indexOf children (:node node)))
    (.indexOf tree node)))


(defn bfs [tree]
  (loop [queue tree
         parent-map {}
         ret []]
    (if (not-empty queue)
      (let [node (first queue)
            rst (vec (rest queue))]
        (cond
          (map? node)
          (recur rst
                 parent-map
                 (conj ret (assoc node :parent (find-parent-id node parent-map) 
                                       :index (find-index node parent-map tree))))
          (vector? node)
          (let [parent-id (gensym)]
            (recur (into rst node)
                   (add-parent parent-map parent-id node)
                   (conj ret {:id parent-id 
                              :index (find-index node parent-map tree)
                              :parent (find-parent-id node parent-map)})))))
      ret)))
```

```clj
(def tree  (attach-ids [:a [:b :c] :d]))
(bfs tree)

;; children with :parent nil value point to root
;;[{:node :a, :id G__21504, :parent nil, :index 0}
;; {:id G__21513, :index 1}
;; {:node :d, :id G__21507, :parent nil, :index 2}
;; {:node :b, :id G__21505, :parent G__21513, :index 0}
;; {:node :c, :id G__21506, :parent G__21513, :index 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good! A problem I see is that non-leaf nodes don't indicate their parent. So, for instance if we do `(def raw-tree [:a [:b] [[:c]]])` , `(def tree (attach-ids raw-tree))` , then `(bfs tree)` gives `[{:node :a, :id G__43138, :parent nil, :index 0}
 {:id G__43153, :index 1}
 {:id G__43154, :index 2}
 {:node :b, :id G__43139, :parent G__43153, :index 0}
 {:id G__43155, :index 0}
 {:node :c, :id G__43140, :parent G__43155, :index 0}]` , so we don't know who is the parent of `G__43155` (its parent is `G__43154` , but that's not reflected). Sorry if I'm missing something!

Comment: Added a call to find-parent for non leaf nodes. It should work now.

Answer (score 1):

When a tree resists tail recursion, another thing to try is a "zipper" from Clojure's standard library.  Zippers shine for editing, but they're also pretty good at linearizing depth-first traversal while keeping structure context available.  A typical zipper loop looks like this:

```
user> (def abcd '(:a (:b :c) :d))
#'user/abcd'
user> (loop [ret [], z (zip/seq-zip abcd)] 
        (if (zip/end? z)
          ret
          (let [o {:name 42, :content (zip/node z), :parent 42, :index 42}]
            (recur (conj ret o) (zip/next z)))))
[{:name 42, :content (:a (:b :c) :d), :parent 42, :index 42}
 {:name 42, :content :a, :parent 42, :index 42}
 {:name 42, :content (:b :c), :parent 42, :index 42}
 {:name 42, :content :b, :parent 42, :index 42}
 {:name 42, :content :c, :parent 42, :index 42}
 {:name 42, :content :d, :parent 42, :index 42}]
```

To fill in `:parent` and `:index`, you'll find zipper notation for looking "up" at parents, "left" for siblings, etc., in the official docs at https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.zip-api.html.

I created the zip with `seq-zip` having modeled nodes as a list. Your specific case models nodes as *vectors*, which `seq-zip` does not recognize, so you would presumably use `vector-zip` or invent your own adapter.  You can follow the "Source" link in the docs to see how `seq-zip` and `vector-zip` work.

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting, but I'm having trouble getting it to work as intended. Using vector-zip solves the problem of the input format, I generate :name with (gensym), :content behaves a little different but close enough, but I haven't figured out how to get :parent to have as value the :name of the parent node, and :index to display the position of the node, as shown in the example.